# org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport out has not been set

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, webservice-client

I have a big problem with WS with Axis2

**use case (localhost server, no internet access [under proxy])**:

I have created a little local web service and a client which calls this service....
endpoint is something like this "http://localhost:8080/MyService"

that's all ok:  client requests and server responses!!

i'm bas***d and i want test my client, so i have changed endpoint in "http://localhost:8082/MyService" (port is changed)

that's all ok: client requests...and it goes in timeout...no service responds on 8082

tests go on:
i have the same web service on internet, so i change my endpoint client in "http://wsdomain:8080/MyService"...without touching proxy conf (on client.axis2.xml)

client requests....and i receive an exception:

`org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport out has not been set`

so, i have setted proxy in client.axis.xml...I have substituted this:

```
<transportSender name="http" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender">
    <parameter name="PROTOCOL">HTTP/1.1</parameter>
    <parameter name="Transfer-Encoding">chunked</parameter>
</transportSender>
```

with this:

```
<transportSender name="http" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender">
    <parameter name="Proxy">
        <Configuration>
            <ProxyHost>MyproxyIp</ProxyHost>
            <ProxyPort>MyproxyPort</ProxyPort>
        </Configuration>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="PROTOCOL">HTTP/1.1</parameter>
    <parameter name="Transfer-Encoding">chunked</parameter>
</transportSender>
```

but my client throws the same exception: 
`org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport out has not been set`

what i miss??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok I have resolved this issue...I thought the problem was in proxy configuration...but my issue was a white space in url string....AAAARRGH...i think this exception is too generic and it doesn't explain the issue

Comment: Please delete this answer

Comment: I had the same error where a whitespace in the config was causing this error . So let's leave the answer.