# Axis2: Transport out has not been set

Tags: java, client, apache-axis

I am writing a SOAP client using axis2. I fetched the wsdl file and generated a stub class. Then I try to call the remove service like this:

```
RequestObj req = new RequestObj();
req.setParam("xxxxx");

ServicePortStub stub = new ServicePortStub();       
ResponseObj res = stub.remoteService(req);
```

But I got an exception `org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport out has not been set` at calling `remoteService`. Any idea?

Comment: Axis generic error, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427900/org-apache-axis2-axisfault-transport-out-has-not-been-set

Comment: That piece of Axis2 code was written in the fail-late style, therefore the generic exception. At the point where it is thrown, the real cause of error has already been lost.

Comment: @Marko how to make it non-fail-late?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not up to you---it's the way the Axis2 developers designed it. The best you can do is file a report to their Jira or whatever they are using for issue tracking.